# LinkedIn - Getting error while searching the people

Tags: objective-c, ios7, linkedin-api

I am using the **LinkedIn api** in my application. As I **search people** from my application. I get **successful Authentication and get logged user profile**. But when I try to search people from app then it gives me the below error.

```
{
    errorCode = 0;
    message = "Access to people search denied.";
    requestId = J3XWUDNQGX;
    status = 403;
    timestamp = 1397118995510;
}
```

Here is the code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?first-name=Andru&last-name=John"];
OAMutableURLRequest *request =

[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:consumer
                                   token:accessToken
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(searchApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(searchApiCallResult:didFail:)];
[request release];
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: what u have tried post some code?

Comment: I have update the question. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

When you register your app by default you have just the basic profile member permissions.
To retrieve your connections, you'll need to have the r_network member permissions.

Make sure that you have that permission granted.

Check out this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

Comment: I have already set the r_network permission, but still its given me same error.